# Vite dynamic base url on runtime

Tags: vue.js, electron, vite

I fixed this problem on prod but not on dev mode.
I'm trying to configure Vite to serve my Vue app remotly to a local electron app.
Electron will fetch the app from a static url and then proxify it to load local ressources.

This proxied url is always dynamic as port and appId could change.

Example:

Remote app URL:

```
http://domain.host/my-app/
```

Local URL:

```
http://localhost:9876/__apps/d530556d3802ea658fa34c07f32888f6/
```

I'm trying to reproduce the same behaviour as './' in webpack.

I tried to use [this experimental feature](https://vitejs.dev/guide/build#advanced-base-options) without success or I didn't quite understand it.

My base url is set to './' for embedded deployment

Thanks for your interest.